# Get Array value by string of keys

Tags: php, arrays, templating

I'm building a template engine for my next project, which is going great. It replaces `{tag}` with a corresponding value.

I want `{tag[0][key]}` to be replaced as well. All I need to know is how to get the value, if I have the string representation of the array and key, like this:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'key' => 'value'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'key' => 'value2'
    )
);

$tag = 'arr[0][key]';

echo($$tag);
```

This is a very simple version of the problem, I hope you understand it. Or else I would be happy to answer any questions about it.

Comment: I am fairly confused. You are trying to access $tag[0][key] which I assume is the same as $arr[0][key]... So then what is the question?

Comment: Seriously, what do you gain by writing `{tag[0][key]}` over `<?php echo $tag[0]['key'] ?>` and how is that novel from the gazillion poor other template engines out there that you think you need to reinvent it?

Comment: Template engines suck. There is no reason to create such an overhead instead writing some php code.

Comment: @Nitroware sorry the {tag[0][key]} was just an example. If i had an var with the value of arr[0][key] how would i get the value from $arr?

@Gordon well, i have a guy doing the html, and this simplyfies it for him. And then i'm doing it for the challenge of it, to expand to horizon and stuff ;)

Comment: @Bried: PHP *IS* a template engine. Running a template engine on PHP is like driving your car to work by loading it onto the back of a flatbed truck - useless overhead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree that there is no need to reinvent the wheel: PHP itself was born as a template engine, and is still good at doing this:

```
<?php echo $arr[0][key]; ?>
```

It even used to have the now deprecated form

```
<?= $arr[0][key] ?>
```

In any case you could do the following

```
$keys = array();
preg_match_all('|\[([^\]]*)\]|', $tag, $keys);
$result = $arr;
foreach ($keys[1] as $key) {
    $result = $result[$key];
}
echo "$result\n";
```

Comment: Hello, you got the idea. I must admit your comments regarding the usefullness of the templating system are very true. Creating the system though has been a great challenge for me and i learned alot about static vars, methods, currying and more! Your answer was exactly what i was looking for, thank you!